# enabled select option within the row with checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Please help i want to enable select with checkbox if the checkbox is checked within the row. the code only works within the first row but the rest is not working. the id of my checkbox is roomCheck and name is chkbox

```
<table name = "mytab1" id = "MyTable" border = "1">
    <tr>
        <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "chkbox" id = "roomCheck"></td>
        <td><select id = "number" disabled><option>test</option></select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "chkbox"></td>
         <td><select id = "number" disabled><option>test</option></select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "chkbox" id = "roomCheck"></td>
        <td><select id = "number" disabled><option>test</option></select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "chkbox" id = "roomCheck"></td>
        <td><select id = "number" disabled><option>test</option></select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "chkbox" id = "roomCheck"></td>
        <td><select id = "number" disabled><option>test</option></select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "chkbox" id = "roomCheck"></td>
        <td><select id = "number" disabled><option>test</option></select>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
                          var update = function () {
                            if ($("#roomCheck").is(":checked")) {
                                $('#number').prop('disabled', false);
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#number').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                            }       
                          };
                          $(update);
                          $("#roomCheck").change(update);
                        </script>
</script>
```

Comment: We use `id`s to identify items separately. Use different ids or use a class name.

Comment: Is this the needed goal? https://jsfiddle.net/oo3b9zm2/1/

Comment: One of the ways to achieve it is with the sample provided by @whitelettersinblankpapers

Comment: @Alariva, question is not clear. If the behaviour that OP needs is the one in fiddle, then there are other ways to achieve it. For example replacing  `$(this).parents().eq(1).find('select')` by a `.closest()` function.

Answer (score -1):

When you use selectors with **id** you must always give a *unique* name to each **id**, this is **html** basics, and this is why it is only working for the first row, the next ones are not identificable.

Suggested to read about [jquery selectors.](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

There are many ways to achieve your goal but you must first change your naming for ids, they must be unique, or you can face this problem by using *class* selectors, among others.

Comment: Alariva is right. that explain in words the fiddle already created

Answer (score -1):

This is the code I ended up using that fixed the issue

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      // Disable select elements
      $('select').each(function() {
         $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
      });

      // Enable them on click

       $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
            if($(this).closest("tr").find("td").children("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked"))
            {           
                $(this).closest("tr").find("td").children("select").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).closest("tr").find("td").children("select").attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
       });
});
```

Comment: does it mean you are going to keep the same markup?